# A mass weighing $16$ pounds stretches a spring $\frac{8}{3}$ feet

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

A mass weighing $16$ pounds stretches a spring $\frac{8}{3}$ feet. The mass if initially released from rest from a point $4$ feet below the equilibrium position and the subsequent motion takes place in a medium that offers a damping force is $\frac{1}{2}$ times $x^{'}$ where $x=x(t)$. The mass is driven by external force given by $f(t)=20cos(3t)$. Convert mass = $\frac{weight}{32}$, Hook's constant Weight = k (length of stretch). Also the position below equilibrium is positive, and the downward motion is positive. Find the equation of motion.

**My Working**

Since the position below equilibrium is positive and the downward motion is positive we have:

$$x(0)=4$$ $$x'(0)=0$$

Now I have figured out the above initial conditions but can't seem to form the resulting differential equation of this problem. Once I do it, I can solve for the $x(t).$ Can anyone help in it. I will really appreciate that.

Comment: Hint: This is a damped and driven harmonic oscillator.  The solution to such is $m\ddot{x}+A\dot{x}+kx=C$, where A is the damping force, k is the spring constant, and C is the driving force

Comment: I have slight problem. According to you $A$ is damping force then from the statement of the problem we see that $A=2\dot{x}$, now When we put the value of $A$ the result is the non-linear DE.  Isn't that?

Comment: The unit of $x'$ would be something like feet/fortnight, which is certainly not a unit of force?! And $f(t)$ carries no unit at all -- I don't know how to interpret this problem statement

Comment: How do you approach $A$ - the damping force?

Comment: @Ameer786: In my setup, A=2 (the $\dot{x}$ is implied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

After the $k$ determination from static considerations, we have

$$
m \ddot x = -\mu \dot x - k x + f(t),\ \ \ x(0)=4,\ \dot x(0) = 0
$$

here $\mu = \frac 12$